# Django Template For Loop - reverese last two iterations

Tags: python, django, for-loop, django-templates

I am using Django 1.10 and Python 3.5.

I have been given some code that consists of a for loop that returns **3 iterations** of value in alphabetical order.

For example the for loop returns: `Chronological, Combination, Functional`.

However I need the for loop to return: **`Chronological, Functional, Combination`** (the last two iterations/values are reversed). I am forced to keep the for loop.

Is this at all possible with a for loop?

I have tried combining `{% if forloop.last %}` with `{% if forloop.first%}` and also setting the value with `{% if forloop.counter == 2 %}...set value to Functional...{% endif %}`  and `{% if forloop.counter == 3 %}...set value to Combination...{% endif %}` but I cannot get this to achieve what I want.

Here is my code:

```
{% for resume_format_image in resume_format_images %}
    <div class="col-md-4">
        {% with "resumes/resume_format_description_"|add:resume_format_image.style.lower|add:".html" as template_name %}
            {% include template_name %}
        {% endwith %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: "I am forced to keep the for loop." - why?

Comment: I don't know that there's a way to do exactly what you're asking, however, some things you might try are [regrouping](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) to change the sort order by some value besides the alphabetical order, or, if you know exactly what's being returned you can skip the forloop and manually create the 3 columns pushing the data into each one by the key as in: `resume_format_images.0.style.lower|add:".html"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured this out:

```
{% for resume_format_image in resume_format_images %}
    <div class="col-md-4">
        {% if forloop.first%}
            {% include "resumes/resume_format_description_chronological.html" %}
        {% elif forloop.last%}
            {% include "resumes/resume_format_description_combination.html" %}
        {% else %}
            {% include "resumes/resume_format_description_functional.html" %}
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I hope this helps someone.